# How to get detailed information of ANOVA procedure in R?

Tags: r, anova

I am doing an anova for a variable divided into 9 categories.

```
av <- aov(Z~Climes)
```

where Z is a vector containing values and Climes contains 9 categories by which anova is to be performed, bear in mind that the number of samples in each category is slightly different.

Now i want a detailed output (e.g. JMP provides me a 9*9 matrix that gives paired comparisons for every category pair i.e. t-test results).

Does the output object of class `aov` hold this information?  If it does i cannot see it in documentation , if no is there another function to perform detailed ANOVA in R?

Comment: If anyone can just alternative multiple comparison procedures in r that is helpful too

Comment: The method you request is methodologically unsound.

Comment: As in am i missing something ?

Comment: As in not supported by sound statistical principles.

Comment: See [multcomp](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/multcomp/index.html) and [multcompView](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/multcompView/index.html) packages.

Comment: i will revisit the statistical principles and check the multcomp package ..looks helpful

Comment: @DWin: not necessarily. For example, Tukey's range test provides a statistically accepted way to do multiple pairwise t-test comparisons and determine which means are significantly greater than others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your first question, **no**: Your `aov` object contains information on model fit, as requested, not *post-hoc* comparisons. It won't even assess distributional assumptions (of the residuals), test of homoskedasticity and the like, and this is not what we expect to see in an ANOVA table anyway. However, you are free (and it is highly recommend, of course) to complement your analysis by assessing model fit, checking assumptions, etc.

About your second question. Multiple comparisons are handled separately, using e.g. `pairwise.t.test()` (with or without correction for multiple tests), `TukeyHSD()` (usually works best with well-balanced data), the [multcomp](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/multcomp/index.html) (see `glht()`), as pointed out by @MYaseen208, or [multtest](http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/multtest.html) package. Some of those tests will assume that the ANOVA F-test was significant, other procedures are more flexible, but it all depends on what you want to do and if it sounds like a reasonable approach to the problem at hand (cf. @DWin's comment). So why R would provide them automatically?

As an illustration, consider the following simulated dataset (a balanced one-way ANOVA):

```
dfrm <- data.frame(x=rnorm(100, mean=10, sd=2), 
                   grp=gl(5, 20, labels=letters[1:5]))
```

where group means and SDs are as follows:

```
+-------+-+---+---------+--------+
|       | | N | Mean    | SD     |
+-------+-+---+---------+--------+
|grp    |a| 20|10.172613|2.138497|
|       |b| 20|10.860964|1.783375|
|       |c| 20| 9.910586|2.019536|
|       |d| 20| 9.458459|2.228867|
|       |e| 20| 9.804294|1.547052|
+-------+-+---+---------+--------+
|Overall| |100|10.041383|1.976413|
+-------+-+---+---------+--------+
```

With JMP, we have a non-significant F(4,95)=1.43 and the following results (I asked for pairwise t-tests):

[image]
(P-values are shown in the last column.)

Note that those t-tests are not protected against Type I error inflation.

With R, we would do:

```
aov.res <- aov(x ~ grp, data=dfrm)
with(dfrm, pairwise.t.test(x, grp, p.adjust.method="none"))
```

You can check what is stored in `aov.res` by issuing `str(aov.res)` at the R prompt. Tukey HSD tests can be carried out using either

```
TukeyHSD(aov.res)  # there's a plot method as well
```

or

```
library(multcomp)
glht(aov.res, linfct=mcp(grp="Tukey"))  # also with a plot method
```